# R: how to match multiple variables within given range(s)

Tags: r, dplyr, match

Here are my data

```
df <- data.frame(peak = c(1:5), RT = c(3, 3.6, 4, 4.1, 5), MZ = c(100, 200, 900, 100, 700))
library <- data.frame(Compound = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"), RT = c(3.11, 3.2, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, 4.9, 5), MZ = c(101, 200, 500, 250, 300, 330, 701, 702))
```

The df:

```
> df
  peak  RT  MZ
1    1 3.0 100
2    2 3.6 200
3    3 4.0 900
4    4 4.1 100
5    5 5.0 700
```

And the library

```
> library
  Compound   RT  MZ
1        A 3.11 101
2        B 3.20 200
3        C 4.00 500
4        D 4.10 250
5        E 4.20 300
6        F 4.40 330
7        G 4.90 701
8        H 5.00 702
```

I want to use the table to match the library to find targeted Compound, the criteria is RT deviation c(-0.5, 0.5) and MZ deviation c(-5, 5). So an ideal result will be like:

```
  peak  RT  MZ Compound
1    1 3.0 100        A
2    2 3.6 200        B
3    3 4.0 900       NA
4    4 4.1 100       NA
5    5 5.0 700     G, H
```

Also, would be nice to work it out without for loop because my actual list is pretty long...

Comment: Please share reproducible data. Not pictures or links. Thanks

Comment: Look, the data is included in the last sentence

Comment: Not that this is much better. Try including your data with `dput`or something similar please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `crossing` from `tidyr` to create all combination of `library` and `df`. Using `filter` we only keep those rows which are in range and collapse the `Compound` for each `peak`.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(library, setNames(df, c('peak', 'RT1', 'MZ1'))) %>%
  filter(abs(RT - RT1) <= 0.5 & abs(MZ - MZ1) <= 5) %>%
  group_by(peak) %>%
  summarise(Compound = toString(Compound)) %>%
  right_join(df, by = 'peak')

#   peak Compound    RT    MZ
#  <int> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 A          3     100
#2     2 B          3.6   200
#3     3 NA         4     900
#4     4 NA         4.1   100
#5     5 G, H       5     700
```